# Isomorphic React.js & iso-http

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a react web application which I'd like to render both server side and client side. I've been working off [isomorphic-react-template](https://github.com/gpbl/isomorphic-react-template) but I've used [iso-http](https://github.com/jedmao/iso-http) to make a query to my content server. My aim is to have the app when server-side query the content server directly and render the content to HTML; and to have the app when client-side to do a normal AJAX request for content.

Here's the code I'm using. It works great on the browser, but the server-side render doesn't include the data; I presume because the server-side render isn't waiting for the async http call to return before it compiles the HTML and sends it over:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
  var id = this.getParams().id;
  var classThis = this;

  request
  .get("http://content.example.com/things/" + id)
  .end(function(response) {
    response.body = JSON.parse(response.text);
    if (response.ok) {
      classThis.setState({ data: response.body });
    } else {
      classThis.setState({ data: null });
    }
  });
}
```

I know this is all fairly new stuff; but is there a known way to solve this problem, so that the server side renderer waits for certain async calls to complete before sending?

Comment: `componentDidMount` doesn't ever run on the server. You have to render to string with the data in-hand (instead of requesting it).

Comment: Is there a "best practice" way of running different code on server and browser then? I could abstract the data retrieval function out then call it from `componentDidMount` on the browser and from `getInitialState` on the server. Seems a bit kludgy, but I'm prepared to accept its necessity.

Comment: It looks like I'm asking this question: https://github.com/reactjs/react-page/issues/47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this working with [react-async](https://github.com/andreypopp/react-async#rendering-async-components-on-server-with-fetched-async-state).

I've pulled out my async function like this so I can call it from `componentDidMount` and from the *asynchronous* `getInitialStateAsync` function that `ReactAsync` uses:

```
mixins: [ ReactAsync.Mixin ],

getInitialStateAsync: function(callback) {
  this.getContent(function(state) {
    callback(null, state)
  }.bind(this))
},

componentDidMount: function() {
  this.getContent(function(state) {
    this.setState(state);
  }.bind(this));
},

getContent: function(callback) {
  var id = this.getParams().id;
  request
    .get("http://content.example.com/things/" + id)
    .end(function(response) {
      response.body = JSON.parse(response.text);
      if (response.ok) {
        callback({ error: {}, post: response.body })
      } else {
        callback({ post: {}, error: response.body });
      }
    });
}
```

Then in my `server.jsx` I'm rendering with the async functions:

```
ReactAsync.renderToStringAsync(<Handler />, function(err, markup) {
  var html   = React.renderToStaticMarkup(<Html title={title} markup={markup} />);
  res.send('<!DOCTYPE html>' + html);
});
```

Obviously there is huge potential for cock up here (the whole page fails to render if the server isn't present) but this feels like the start of the right approach!